# Dynamic generated checkboxes all is checked when one is clicked when v-model is applied

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox

I have some checkboxes that are generated dynamically, once one of the checkboxes is clicked the others all get checked vice versa when unchecked. But this only happens when binding with v-model. I'm curious because, I've used the same style before, and worked just fine.

Here are a few snippets

```
<div v-for="deduction in deductions" :key="deduction.id" class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input class="form-check-input" :name="deduction.title" v-model="salaryForm.selectedDeductions"  v-bind:value="deduction" :id="deduction.id" type="checkbox">
<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">{{ deduction.title }}</label>
</div>
               
<div>{{ salaryForm.selectedDeductions}}</div>
```

Here is my data

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
               deductions: [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Pension",
        "isPercent": 1,
        "percentage": 2,
        "isActual": 0,
        "actual": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T17:44:05.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T18:52:36.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Lateness",
        "isPercent": 0,
        "percentage": null,
        "isActual": 1,
        "actual": 400,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T18:22:50.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T18:28:55.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Housing",
        "isPercent": 1,
        "percentage": 3.2,
        "isActual": 0,
        "actual": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T19:53:08.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T19:53:08.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Car",
        "isPercent": 1,
        "percentage": 2,
        "isActual": 0,
        "actual": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:04.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:04.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Medical",
        "isPercent": 0,
        "percentage": null,
        "isActual": 1,
        "actual": 5000,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:48.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Transportation",
        "isPercent": 0,
        "percentage": null,
        "isActual": 1,
        "actual": 2000,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:16:29.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:16:29.000000Z"
    }] 
               salaryForm: new Form ({
                  id: '',
                  name: '',
                  salary: '',
                  commission: 0,
                  selectedDeductions: [ ],
                  amount_to_paid: '',
                  comment: '',

              }),
            }
        },
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: After the edit, the code works as expected.  See demonstration below. (Note the only change was to replace new Form with a flat object).  If the code is still failing, it must have something to do with the Form object not included in the OP,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form` object declared in the data is not responsive (does not have responsive properties).  Declare the form data as a simple object, and build the form `new Form(this.salaryForm)`. At submission time.

See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for more detail about responsive properties.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      deductions: [{
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Pension",
          "isPercent": 1,
          "percentage": 2,
          "isActual": 0,
          "actual": null,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T17:44:05.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T18:52:36.000000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Lateness",
          "isPercent": 0,
          "percentage": null,
          "isActual": 1,
          "actual": 400,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T18:22:50.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T18:28:55.000000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": "Housing",
          "isPercent": 1,
          "percentage": 3.2,
          "isActual": 0,
          "actual": null,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T19:53:08.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T19:53:08.000000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "title": "Car",
          "isPercent": 1,
          "percentage": 2,
          "isActual": 0,
          "actual": null,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:04.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:04.000000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "title": "Medical",
          "isPercent": 0,
          "percentage": null,
          "isActual": 1,
          "actual": 5000,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:48.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:14:48.000000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "title": "Transportation",
          "isPercent": 0,
          "percentage": null,
          "isActual": 1,
          "actual": 2000,
          "created_at": "2021-07-28T20:16:29.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-07-28T20:16:29.000000Z"
        }
      ],
      salaryForm: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        salary: '',
        commission: 0,
        selectedDeductions: [],
        amount_to_paid: '',
        comment: '',
      },
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ salaryForm.selectedDeductions.map(o => o.title) }}</pre>

  <div v-for="deduction in deductions" :key="deduction.id" class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" :name="deduction.title" v-model="salaryForm.selectedDeductions" v-bind:value="deduction" :id="deduction.id" type="checkbox">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">{{ deduction.title }}</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's the funny thing. It's not. I can't warp my head around why.

Comment: Then I must misunderstand the expectation, @Willydbd.  I see the checkboxes selected one at a time, not all at once as the OP states.  Edited to present model in the view, as further confirmation.

Comment: I don't think you misunderstood the qst. On my machine it's selecting all at once NOT one at a time. I've cleared all my browsers(3) cache but same result. I have another component I did something similar that is working correctly. If I removed the v-model then would work rightly. Really appreciate you, thanks for your help

Comment: Are you able to run the snippet in my answer (on the same browser)?  Does the snippet work as expected?  I think it will. If your exact same code on the same browser doesn't work, then I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes, it does work as expected, but now in my main code NO. In my main code, it clicked one at a time but didn't bind the value to the property (selectedDeductions). I found a way around it for now tho. I defined the array outside the salaryForm object. That way it worked just fine. My question is then WHY?

Comment: That's a valuable hint! Your work-around works and my suggestion works...what's different about them and the original code?  It's `new Form()`. When you create one of those in data, you are not creating reactive properties.  (see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).  What to do about it?  It depends on what you use the Form class for.  One idea is to only create the Form object with the regular reactive data at the time of submission.

Comment: Can you please include this comment in your answer. So I can mark it correct so for others who may experience similar issue to see it. Cheers for your valuable time. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that makes sense. The only issue I am seeing now is that you have enclosed your form object inside of `new Form` first off Form is not defined in your example code, therefore I assume you are intending to use `FormData`, or some other library I am not familiar with. If this is the case and you are intending to be using `FormData` for sending the data back to your server. Then you should be enclosing your object when you are making the API request.

Therefore your data would change to have the form object defined as so

```js
 data() {
    return {
      salaryForm: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        salary: "",
        commission: 0,
        selectedDeductions: [],
        amount_to_paid: "",
        comment: "",
      },
   }
}
```

Then in your API call, you would use the inbuilt [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) class to post back to the server.

```
const formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(this.salaryForm).forEach((key) =>
  formData.append(key, this.salaryForm[key])
);
//Make API request
```

Here is a [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-tdd-squio?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:587-797) with an example

Comment: I'm so sorry, I made mistake in my question, your answer brought my attention to it. I've edited now. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Multiple checkboxes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox), you have to give an array in v-model, an array that will contain selected checkedboxes values. while here you send a  preset array value that will not be binded to.

Just to say if you can have another array (selected:[]) in salaryForm that will receive all the selected checkboxes values it will work.

```
<input 
class="form-check-input"  
:name="deduction.title"  
v-model="salaryForm.selected"   
v-bind:value="deduction"  
:id="deduction.id"  
type="checkbox">
```

...

```
 data() {
        return {
           salaryForm: new Form ({
              id: '',
              name: '',
              salary: '',
              commission: 0,
selected:[],
                  selectedDeductions: [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Pension",
        "isPercent": 1,
        "percentage": 2,
        "isActual": 0,
        "actual": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-28T17:44:05.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T18:52:36.000000Z"
    },
    ...
        ],
          

amount_to_paid: '',
              comment: '',
              }),
            }
```

Comment: My bad, I made mistake in my question just seeing realizing now seeing another comment. Cheers for your time, I've edited it.